# Use PHP if() to match item in array

Tags: php, arrays, find

I am working on an admin panel in which the code will display different if the PDO query returns all the admins from the admin table and the userid matches 1 of the admin id results. Only there can be an unlimited amount of admins and I don't want to be editing the code for each of them.

Would it be possible to do this (pseudo code):

`if($userid isfoundin $result['admin_user_id']{
      -- admin code here
   }`

I haven't yet written the admin table as I want more info on it first but if I cycle through the user table and look for id `$query->fetchAll()` then I get this:

```
   array(30) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" [0]=> string(1) "7" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" [0]=> string(1) "6" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" [0]=> string(1) "8" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31" [0]=> string(2) "31" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "26" [0]=> string(2) "26" } [5]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" [0]=> string(1) "4" } [6]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "35" [0]=> string(2) "35" } [7]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "21" [0]=> string(2) "21" } [8]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "38" [0]=> string(2) "38" } [9]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "24" [0]=> string(2) "24" } [10]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "34" [0]=> string(2) "34" } [11]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "20" [0]=> string(2) "20" } [12]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" [0]=> string(2) "19" } [13]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "23" [0]=> string(2) "23" } [14]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "33" [0]=> string(2) "33" } [15]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" [0]=> string(2) "28" } [16]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" } [17]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" [0]=> string(2) "15" } [18]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" [0]=> string(1) "9" } [19]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "25" [0]=> string(2) "25" } [20]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" } [21]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "32" [0]=> string(2) "32" } [22]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" [0]=> string(1) "5" } [23]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "18" [0]=> string(2) "18" } [24]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "29" [0]=> string(2) "29" } [25]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "27" [0]=> string(2) "27" } [26]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "30" [0]=> string(2) "30" } [27]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "22" [0]=> string(2) "22" } [28]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" [0]=> string(2) "10" } [29]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "36" [0]=> string(2) "36" } }
```

this si what I am trying to use right now

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/settings.php";
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users");
$query->execute();
var_dump($query->fetchAll());
if (in_array($user['id'], $query->fetchAll())){
    echo $user['id'];
}
```

Comment: the `in_array` function will do the work , but only if `$result['admin_user_id']` is an array of your `admin's ids`

Comment: @ofirbaruch wait but in pdo you do foreach as $var then would this still work?

Comment: Does `$result['admin_user_id']` contain an array?

Comment: @MuqMan , we need more information about your situation. Your table's structre , what's the content of the `results['admin_user_id']` variable? paste more code please.

Comment: wait a min guys, let me just get that data.

Comment: @ofirbauch i have posted the code!

Comment: @saji89 no, i just realized but i edited the code, take a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes, you can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this.

I assume that you have a set of users for admin. Say, it is:

```
$adminUsers = array("admin", "administrator");
# Or by your code
$adminUsers = $result['admin_user_id'];
```

Now the code part is like:

```
if (in_array($userid, $adminUsers))
    // Admin code here
```

Comment: I have heard of such but can you please show me some code? I did google it but nothing that was like my situation.

Comment: there are examples right on that manual page that he linked to.

Comment: @MuqMan You are too fast. Posted the code. Added something relevant to your code too! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in-array) to see if a given item is in an array.

Comment: wait so it would be if($userid in_array($admin['user_id'])?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `in_array()` if all you need to know is that the user ID exists in your array.

But if you actually need a reference to the item, take a look at `array_search()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through all the users in your admins table and then having another loop in order to find if a specific user exists , why not doing this check in the query itself?

For instance:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name,email FROM admins WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("d", $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $email);

    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //The user with user_id exists in the admins table , show him the admin panel.
        //You can use $name and $email.
    }

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer IMO.  Everyone else (including me) was too focused on the "_Would it be possible to do this..._" part of the question, but this answer better addresses the overall requirement.